# Android: onPreparePanel(...) is not being called

Tags: android, dialog

In my application, I am using a custom dialog to get some information before creating a new object.  The contents of some of the text fields are preserved each time the dialog is called (default behavior), but I want to clear the "name" field each time so the user must enter a new name.  To do this, I was using `onPreparePanel(...)` to clear the field before the dialog is displayed.

According to the documentation, `onPreparePanel(...)` is called "called right before the panel window is shown, every time it is shown."

This method is never being called in my custom dialog class!

Here is the custom dialog (MyDialog.java):

```
package com.test.HelloAndroid;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyDialog extends Dialog {

    public MyDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dismiss();
                }

        });
    }
}
```

This code uses the `showDialog(int)` mechanism to display the dialog.  Here is the main:

```
package com.test.HelloAndroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(0);
            }

        });
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        return new MyDialog(this);
    }    
}
```

The XML for the my_dialog layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:text="@string/hello"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The XML for the main layout is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Button" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/button1"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code here:

```
@Override
public boolean onPreparePanel(int featureId, View view, Menu menu) {
    return true;
}
```

Shouldn't you have some extra code there to do the clear for you? You are just returning true there.

Comment: Correct!  But the method isn't being called at all!  This SSCCE just shows the structure of my code.  In my environment, I am placing a breakpoint in this method and it is never getting triggered.